# Eclipse BIRT Reporting - 'Drop' cross tab cell property value can't be changed

Tags: eclipse, birt

basically the title says it all but to be more specific my problem is that even though I found the 'Drop' property under the advanced tab of a cross tab cell in BIRT I can't change the value and it says 'None : Inherited' and I can't figure out why. I'm using the free version of BIRT (Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2), Build id: 20150219-0600).

What might prevent me from changing this property's value?

Comment: Indeed it can't be changed in a crosstab, but what should  we expect this property to do in a crosstab? Actually it seems to me that crosstabs natively act like if a drop property was enabled, because labels of successive row groups are displayed side by side.

Comment: I need it to display the not changing (grouped by) rows also in every single row, so not only when something changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually found the solution to my problem: the first column of the cross tab has to contain unique values and